# Whose flashbacks is Sam experiencing?

Tags: death-stranding

The flashbacks Sam is having such as at 1:19:06, is it Sam's own memories or or is it the BB's flashbacks, its memories?

Deadman says it is not Sam's own memories.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that Deadman is wrong. Normally, flashbacks are the result of the connection with the BB and someone with DOOMS as they create a feedback loop. Here, due to unique circumstances, ones unknown to Deadman, Sam is instead able to manifest those flashbacks.

Potential spoiler if you haven't gotten to the end of the game:

> In Sam's case, he was a BB, one of the first ones and [one they thought might have the greatest potential](https://deathstranding.fandom.com/wiki/Die-Hardman%27s_Confession:_Bridget%27s_BB_Experiments_-_Part_2). His father, [Cliff](https://deathstranding.fandom.com/wiki/Cliff_Unger), attempted to rescue him from the facility. They died in the process, Sam was brought back as a repatriate, and Cliff still haunts the game as a BT, the Combat Veteran.

FWIW, [all of the flashbacks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Um-cW3I_h40). May contain further spoilers.

Comment: @GuilhermeWoolley: As I understand it, they can. That's what Deadman is referring to when he talks about the potentially dangerous feedback loop.